# AVCaptureDeviceType crashing on iPad Obejective-C

Tags: xcode, avcam

I am having the same code as on Apple Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Objective_C_AVCam_AVCamCameraViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Objective_C_AVCam_AVCamCameraViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_7

```
NSArray<AVCaptureDeviceType> *deviceTypes = @[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera, AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera];
```

Code breaks on this line.

Stack trace screenshot is attached. [Stack Trace Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1utMd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take reference from the link below.This solved my problem for camera crashing on iPads with lower iOS versions.

https://github.com/imjerrybao/AVCam

> Also make sure where your app is crashing.
>   If it is Crashing because of core data(**NSPersistentContainer**) on lower versions of iOS, try using: **INSPersistentContainer** instead.

https://github.com/inspace-io/INSPersistentContainer